# How to define a function in an implicit form

Tags: functions

Know the 2-variables function $F(x,y)$. How can I define the function $x\to f(x)$ s.t. $F(x,f(x))=0$?

Comment: So you want to solve an equation, right? Did you search for how to solve equations in Mathematica? Please show what you have already tried, and we can go from there.

Comment: Welcome to Mma.SE! Your question needs more from your side. Here it's considered helpful and polite to show your own efforts and share your data and code attempts in a well [formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX), so we can quickly see the problem you are facing. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question accordingly. Also, please take the [tour], it will help you understand the site. Learning about [asking](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O) and what's [on-topic](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O) will help to write an [excellent question](https://goo.gl/BqKxV3) and inspire great answers.

Comment: Note the map from $x$ to $y$ is not necessarily a [function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Function.html), as there could be multiple $y$ for a single $x$.